# nginx does not redirect 404 errors

Tags: nginx

in my website i have only two pages "index.php" and "page.php", whatever i type i get redirected to localhost, for instance if i go to  localhost/randompage instead of being redirected to 404.html i go to localhost (i.e index.php)

here is my conf:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;
root   html;
index  index.php;

    location / {

        if ($request_uri !~* '\/|page\.php\?.*') {
            return 404;
        }

        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    }

    error_page  404              /404.html;
    location = /404.html {
        root   html;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files  $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

}
```

what should i change?

Comment: I don't see any use for the blocks `location = /50x.html` nor `location = /404.html`, you are defining the same root that is already defined on the server scope, then you have an `if` and a `try_files` why not make both the same `try_files` statement, if you explain what exactly you are trying to accomplish I could help you optimize that config file

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady thanks for your help, i'm just trying to make requestes to urls other than {mydomain.com,mydomain.com/index.php,mydomain.com/page.php?var1=&var2=} return a 404 error and then display the 404.html page

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem. Commenting out this line fixed it:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
```

`try_files` checks to see if the given URI works. If not, it tries to see if the given URI works as a directory. Failing that, it redirects to `/index.php`. Without this line, it'll serve up the 404 file indicated with `error_page`.

Hope that works for you.